# Android Preview Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-toolbar

The preview window panel of the android studio displays an error that I should download and SDK, later on when I restart the program, it displays "loading" without any suggestion.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot please?

Answer (score 0):

if you want just show toolbars in preview just try it [image]

[image]